# Checking existing user in database with jquery and servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, post

I have a servlet to check validity of a user in my DB. I have a field which takes the username and on blur an ajax post request is made. But in the browser console I am getting the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:8084/Project/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is the code I am trying with javascript/jquery

```
function checkValidity(str){
    $.post({
        url: "/checkValidity.do",
        data: {"paramType":"username","field":str},
        sucess: function(data){
            if(JSON.parse(data.exists)){
                alert("Account already exists");
                return false;
            } else {
                alert("Not found");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I cannot find where I am doing wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$.post({
```

to

```
$.ajax({
```

and add `type:'POST'`

So complete code would be.

```
function checkValidity(str)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url     : "/checkValidity.do",
        data    : {
            "paramType":"username",
            "field":str
        },
        type    : 'POST',
        sucess  : function(data)
        {
            if(JSON.parse(data.exists)){
                alert("Account already exists");
                return false;
            } else {
                alert("Not found");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But can you tell me what was the problem with the other way.

Comment: @DigvijayYadav you had wrong syntax for `$.post` you were using `$.ajax` options and syntax